# Ошибка валидации частично на английском

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Помогите разобраться, есть проект на ASP.NET MVC, большинство полей валидации проявляют правильно ошибку на русском языке, но поле даты почему то частично пишется на английском, может кто нибудь сталкивался с таким явлением, как исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код JQuery

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.methods, {
    date: function (value, element) {
        let v = $(element).mask();
        return this.optional(element) || v === "" || /^(((0[1-9]{1}|[1-2]{1}[0-9]{1})\.(0[1-9]{1}|1[0-2]{1}))|((30)\.(0[1,3-9]{1}|1[0-2]{1}))|((31)\.(0[1,3,5,7,8]{1}|1[0,2]{1})))\.(19[0-9]{2}|20[0-9]{2})$/.test(value);
    },
    number: function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?: \d{3})+)(?:,\d+)?$/.test(value);
    },

    numberplus: function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:\d{3})+)?(?:,\d+)?$/.test(value);
    }
});
```

Вот код модели

```
[Display(Name = "Дата рождения")]
        public DateTime? birthday { get; set; }
```

Comment: У Вас ошибку что выводит ASP.Net или jQuery? Если ASP.Net, то скорее всего нужно либо пакет локализации добавить, либо добавить свой ресурсы, по примеру оригинала https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.ComponentModel.Annotations/src/Resources/Strings.resx, либо реализовать через свои аннотации, но я думаю, что это излишне.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Ели хотите быстро решить проблему, для валидации на стороне сервера, то уберите атрибут [Display(Name = "Дата рождения")], и тогда ваше предупреждение будет почти на чистом английском: "The field birthday must be a date".
2. Если хотите что бы все было на русском по феншую, то ищите в каком частичном представлении у вас вызывается валидация для данных типа дата. И  изменяйте там все на русский язык.
3. Если хотите чтоб все было красиво и быстро, то используйте библиотеку SweetAlert2, и настраивайте проверку ввода данных в форму на стороне клиента. В этом [коммите](https://github.com/AndyBrizhak/Rocky/commit/c7c2effa2b0c4e8587ce43e43d57abf21970cfff) используется такой тип предупреждений для приложения ASP.NET MVC на .NET 5.